# Setting limit for mootools makeResizable dynamically?

Tags: mootools, drag, resizable

I'm trying to set the upper limit values of a resizable image to keep it within the containing div. I'm using mootools to make the image both moveable and resizable (implementing `Drag.Move` and `makeResizable` to do so.)

My temporary solution is to use `overflow:hidden;` so the resized image does not overtake the rest of the page when it is sized beyond the container, but I'd like to be able to have a way so the image can not be resized outside of its container.

I know that since `limit` is set on `'domready'`, if I try to set it to a variable that changes value as the image is resized (ie: `onDrag`), the limit parameter won't be updated on the fly. I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into how I can achieve a similar effect to the `Drag.Move` `container` parameter, as `makeResizable` doesn't seem to have the same parameter.

HTML:

```
<div id="pImageArea">
    <div id="pLogo" class="displayNone">
        <div id="moveHandleName">
            <img src="uploadedlogo.jpg" id="imgName" /> 
        </div>
        <div id="resizeHandleName"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imageArea {
    float: left;
    width: 630px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#imgContainer {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    border: 1px dashed #333;
    position: absolute;
}
#imgName {
    width: 100%;
}
#moveHandleName {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#resizeHandleName {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 100%;
    margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

JS:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var xLim = 50;
    var yLim = 50;
    // Make image moveable
    new Drag.Move($('imgContainer'), {
        container: $('imageArea'),
        handle: $('imgHandleName')
    });
    // Make image resizable
    $('imgContainer').makeResizable({
        handle:$('handleName'),
        limit: {x: [50, xLim], y: [50, yLim]},
        onDrag: function(el) {
            // Set imgContainer height
            el.setStyle('height', $('imgName').getSize().y + 'px');
            // Set upper limits
            xLim = $('imageArea').getSize().x - el.getSize().x;
            yLim = $('imageArea').getSize().y - el.getSize().y;
        },
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' it like this in my own code (modified to use your element and values):

```
$('imgContainer').retrieve('resizer').setOptions({
    limit: {
        x: [50, xLim],
        y: [50, yLim]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, LH. I wasn't able to replicate success with this method for whatever reason, but the requirements have changes (shocking, I know) to the point where this functionality is no long necessary.

Comment: That's what happens. But what I didn't notice in my answer, is that your logic is wrong. You need to have limits both on move and resize and recalculate the move limit when you resize, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The move limit should be properly enforced once you specify the 'container' option and your container has a set width and height. When you resize, my draggable does not need to have limits (re)set. (Using Moo 1.4 by the way.)
However, resizing does cause problems in conjunction with move and limits. The key is that the 'limit' option is only set when initializing makeResizable(). The only way to update it is by setting it with the code shown above. But you have to update it **right after you dropped** the draggable, because that's the only event that affects the limit. So:

```
// Make image moveable
new Drag.Move($('imgContainer'), {
    container: $('imageArea'),
    handle: $('imgHandleName'),
    onDrop: function() {
        $('imgContainer').retrieve('resizer').setOptions({
        limit: {
            x: [50, $('imageArea').getSize().x - parseInt($('imageArea]).getStyle('left'))],
            y: [50, $('imageArea').getSize().y - parseInt($('imageArea]).getStyle('top'))]
        }
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I've also used getStyle() instead of getPosition() because getPosition() returns a value relative to the window, while Moo sets the draggable top and left relative to the droparea.